# What is loading first in this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http

In terms of loading order, what is happening in this script?  Does the divLoading div tag finish loading before the jquery libraries finish loading?  And, do the libraries start loading before the divLoading div tag is created on the users screen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="divLoading">loading...</div>
        <img src="http://goes.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/goes/060619_fulldisk_color.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS is blocking, so HTML parsing will pause while the scripts are loaded.

Comment: Is it possible to get the divLoading on the users screen before calling the jQuery libraries?

Comment: Move the `<script>` elements to after the `<div>`

Comment: JS is blocking -- Unless you load your scripts asyncronously :-)

Comment: I've moved the script elements to below the closing html, but for some reason the jquery libraries finish loading and are usable before the large image has finished loading.  Shouldn't it wait for the image to finish loading then call the script tags?

Comment: No. Images are non-blocking. (And you aren't allowed to put scripts outside the head or body).

Comment: You should consider using your script to load the image, which is very easy to do var im = new Image(); im.src = ''; im.onLoad = function() {}; and so forth

Comment: No, because you are using on document.ready instead of window.onload

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is requested, jQuery UI is requested. You don't have any JavaScript code to wait for the page to render or anything. You can use Firebug to investigate what gets loaded, when and how long it took:

http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

Scripts are run serially in the order in which they're referenced. So, jQuery will be loaded first and then jQuery UI. (The browser might download both at the same time, and may or may not finish downloading one before the other, but processing will be ran first-in/first-out.)

JavaScript, also, is blocking (nothing else on the page will load), so the scripts will be entirely downloaded and processed before the browser even considers what is in the body tag.

Comment: Unless you load your scripts asyncronously :-)

Comment: Not really applicable to this discussion. Asynchronous JavaScript is referenced and loaded by other JavaScript, not HTML tags, which is what the poster is interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Not to reiterate what has been posted, but the js will load first and will block any other elements from being downloaded, hence it is a best practice to move all of your scripts to the bottom of the page, if you are using jquery, than I am assuming you are using the document.ready listener to wrap all of your actions. If this is the case, any actions would not take place until the DOM is ready so there w(sh)ould be no harm in moving the files.

http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/

This is a good question in that it raises a fundamental concept in HTTP client/server interaction.